# How can I create an accordion with its respective data from a query in MySQL?

Tags: php, html

I already have everything prepared, I am extracting the chapter and the video series, everything up to here without problems:

```
$id_course = 1;
$stmt =  $con->prepare("SELECT c.chapter,
                            v.preview,
                            v.title_video,
                            v.description_video,
                            v.type_format,
                            v.multimedia,
                            v.detail,
                            v.time_video,
                            v.url_website
                        FROM tbl_chapters c
                        JOIN tbl_videos v ON v.id_course = c.id_course AND v.id_chapter = c.id_chapter
                        WHERE c.id_course=?
                        ");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id_course);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {

    $stmt->bind_result($chapter, $preview, $title_video, $description_video, $type_format, $multimedia, $detail, $time_video, $url_website);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {


    }

} else {
    echo "no data!";
}
```

Each chapter `$chapter` has its series of videos, as can be seen in the following format:

```
<div class="modules">
    <button class="accordion">Introduction</button>
    <div id="enlaces" class="section videolist" style="display: none;">
        <a class="link playing" href="#">
            <div class="chapter flex">
                <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                <div><span class="play-title-course">Video 1</span></div>
                <div><span class="time-video">00:41</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link playing" href="#">
            <div class="chapter flex">
                <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                <div><span class="play-title-course">Video 2</span></div>
                <div><span class="time-video">00:41</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>                              
</div>
<div class="modules">
    <button class="accordion">Introduction II</button>
    <div id="enlaces" class="section videolist" style="display: none;">
        <a class="link playing" href="#">
            <div class="chapter flex">
                <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                <div><span class="play-title-course">Class 1</span></div>
                <div><span class="time-video">00:41</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link playing" href="#">
            <div class="chapter flex">
                <div><span class="check-mark"></span></div>
                <div><span class="play-title-course">Class 2</span></div>
                <div><span class="time-video">00:41</span></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>                              
</div>
```

The problem is that if I print this from `$chapter` the cycle, it repeats it to me for each video series that exists and, that should not be the case, I attach a screenshot of what I want to achieve (note: the html format already works as the picture):

[image]

This is the data table:

[image]

Could you please guide me

Comment: Please show the code that does what you describe, as in 'repeats it to me for each video series that exists'.

Comment: @WillWalsh If I do this directly in the cycle, the chapter will be repeated for each video that exists in the videos table: `while ($stmt->fetch()) { echo $chapter; echo $title_video;}`

Comment: @WillWalsh I could not continue for that reason, what I want is to generate that HTML structure that ours in my friend question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the repeating nature of $chapter, use an if statement and a temporary variable. Make the 'cycle' this.

```
$tempChapter = "";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // If you have not yet printed the $chapter, this will be true
  if ($tempChapter != $chapter) {
    echo $chapter;
    // This stores the current chapter in $tempChapter, so this code will not run again until $chapter changes
    $tempChapter = $chapter;
  }
  echo $title_video;
}
```

You should be able to add to this to make the HTML structure you want.